# Impala get the difference between 2 dates excluding weekends

Tags: sql, date, impala, recursive-query

I'm trying to get the day difference between 2 dates in Impala but I need to exclude weekends.

I know it should be something like this but I'm not sure how the weekend piece would go...

```
DATEDIFF(resolution_date,created_date)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One approach at such task is to enumerate each and every day in the range, and then filter out the week ends before counting.

Some databases have specific features to generate date series, while in others offer recursive common-table-expression. Impala does not support recursive queries, so we need to look at alternative solutions.

If you have a table wit at least as many rows as the maximum number of days in a range, you can use `row_number()` to offset the starting date, and then conditional aggregation to count working days.

Assuming that your table is called `mytable`, with column `id` as primary key, and that the big table is called `bigtable`, you would do:

```
select 
    t.id, 
    sum(
        case when dayofweek(dateadd(t.created_date, n.rn)) between 2 and 6 
        then 1 else 0 end
    ) no_days
from mytable t
inner join (select row_number() over(order by 1) - 1 rn from bigtable) n
    on t.resolution_date > dateadd(t.created_date, n.rn)
group by id
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is bigtable? I have one table with dates in two columns and I want to find the date difference between the two, excluding weekends.